# Eclipse Groovy Plugin: A transform used a generics containing ClassNode Entry <List, Iterable> for the method ... directly

Tags: groovy, eclipse-plugin

What should one do with this?

```
protected List<BasePropCont> getChildren( boolean updCacheOn = false,  
  Entry< List, Iterable >  _subIterEntry = null )
{
  return null   
  // orig code removed since it seems not to matter
}
```

show the following as an error:

> Groovy:A transform used a generics containing ClassNode
>
> ```
> Entry <List, Iterable>
> ```
>
> for the method
>
> ```
> protected java.util.List getChildren(boolean updCacheOn, Entry _subIterEntry)  { ... }
> ```
>
> directly.
>   You are not supposed to do this. Please create a new ClassNode referring to the old
>   ClassNode and use the new ClassNode instead of the old one.
>   Otherwise the compiler will create wrong descriptors and a potential 
>   NullPointerException in TypeResolver in the OpenJDK.
>   If this is not your own doing, please report this bug to the writer of the transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hah ... the solution was to **watch the auto-handled imports** with the editors `Save Action`. Somehow the Plugin removed some imports (maybe in a state where there were compile errors present while coding) and among them was

```
import java.util.Map.Entry
```

:-/

Manually adding it solves it.
Had similiar problems with other "disappearing" imports already.

(The actual cause for this strange error may be some (of many found) `Entry` classes from the default Groovy imports or within the scope)